# LeetCode 1707. Maximum XOR With an Element From Array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, max, xor

You are given an array nums consisting of non-negative integers. You are also given a queries array, where queries[i] = [xi, mi].

The answer to the ith query is the maximum bitwise XOR value of xi and any element of nums that does not exceed mi. In other words, the answer is max(nums[j] XOR xi) for all j such that nums[j] <= mi. If all elements in nums are larger than mi, then the answer is -1.

Return an integer array answer where answer.length == queries.length and answer[i] is the answer to the ith query.
This python solution uses Trie, but still LeetCode shows TLE?

```
 import operator

 class TrieNode:
      def __init__(self):
          self.left=None
          self.right=None
   
 class Solution:
     def insert(self,head,x):
         curr=head
         for i in range(31,-1,-1):
             val = (x>>i) & 1
             if val==0:
                if not curr.left:
                   curr.left=TrieNode()
                       curr=curr.left
                   else:
                       curr=curr.left
               else:
                   if not curr.right:
                       curr.right=TrieNode()
                       curr=curr.right
                   else:
                       curr=curr.right
       
           
       def maximizeXor(self, nums: List[int], queries: List[List[int]]) -> List[int]:
           res=[-10]*len(queries)
           nums.sort()
           for i in range(len(queries)):
               queries[i].append(i)
           queries.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
           head=TrieNode()
          
           for li in queries:
               max=0
               xi,mi,index=li[0],li[1],li[2]
               m=2**31
               node = head
               pos=0
               if mi<nums[0]:
                   res[index]=-1
                   continue
               for i in range(pos,len(nums)):
                   if mi<nums[i]:
                       pos=i
                       break
                   self.insert(node,nums[i])
               node=head
               for i in range(31,-1,-1):
                   val=(xi>>i)&1
                   if val==0:
                       if node.right:
                           max+=m
                           node=node.right
                       else:
                           node=node.left
                   else:
                       if node.left:
                           max+=m
                           node=node.left
                       else:
                           node=node.right
                   m>>=1
               res[index]=max
           return -1
```

Comment: For this kind of bit-operation question, it's best to think how to maximize the bit-op results - that's the hint.  You don't need to use Trie, and your implement is not accurate.

Comment: @DanielHao for this sort of query the Trie is actually the way to go. You'll have a rather hard time beating `O(1)` for queries, so unless you're only performing a handful of queries on a large input-dataset, the extra effort of building the trie is definitely justified.

Comment: @Paul you're correct. But seeing someone using bit-trick which is faster than Trie...Agree it's the preferred way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is alternative `Trie` implement to solve this problem:

[Notes: 1) max(x XOR y for y in A);  2) do the greedy on MSB bit; 3) sort the queries]

```
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = {}
    
    def add(self, n):
        p = self.root
        for bitpos in range(31, -1, -1):
            bit = (n >> bitpos) & 1
            if bit not in p:
                p[bit] = {}
            p = p[bit]
    
    def query(self, n):
        p = self.root
        ret = 0
        if not p:
            return -1
        for bitpos in range(31, -1, -1):
            bit = (n >> bitpos) & 1
            inverse = 1 - bit
            if inverse in p:
                p = p[inverse]
                ret |= (1 << bitpos)
            else:
                p = p[bit]
                
        return ret

class Solution:
    def maximizeXor(self, nums: List[int], queries: List[List[int]]) -> List[int]:
        
        n = len(nums)
        trie = Trie()
        q = sorted(enumerate(queries), key = lambda x: x[1][1])
        nums.sort()
        res = [-1] * len(queries)
        i = 0
        for index, (x, m) in q:
            while i < n and nums[i] <= m:
                trie.add(nums[i])
                i += 1
            res[index] = trie.query(x)
        return res
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're building a fresh `Trie` for each query. And to make matters worse, use linear search to find the maximum value `<= mi` in `nums`. You'd be better off by simply using

```
max((n for n in nums if n <= mi), key=lambda n: n^xi, default=-1)
```

The solution here would be to build the trie right at the start and simply filter for values smaller than `mi` using that trie:

```
import math
import bisect

def dump(t, indent=''):
    if t is not None:
        print(indent, "bit=", t.bit, "val=", t.val, "lower=", t.lower)
        dump(t.left, indent + '\tl')
        dump(t.right, indent + '\tr')

class Trie:
    def __init__(self, bit, val, lower):
        self.bit = bit
        self.val = val
        self.lower = lower
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        
    def solve(self, mi, xi):
        print('-------------------------------------------')
        print(self.bit, "mi(b)=", (mi >> self.bit) & 1, "xi(b)=", (xi >> self.bit) & 1, "mi=", mi, "xi=", xi)
        dump(self)
        
        if self.val is not None:
            # reached a leave of the trie => found matching value
            print("Leaf")
            return self.val
        
        if mi & (1 << self.bit) == 0:
            # the maximum has a zero-bit at this position => all values in the right subtree are > mi
            print("Left forced by max")
            return -1 if self.left is None else self.left.solve(mi, xi)
        
        # pick based on xor-value if possible
        if (xi >> self.bit) & 1 == 0 and self.right is not None and (mi > self.right.lower or mi == ~0):
            print("Right preferred by xi")
            return self.right.solve(mi, xi)
        elif (xi >> self.bit) & 1 == 1 and self.left is not None:
            print("Left preferred by xi")
            return self.left.solve(~0, xi)
        
        # pick whichever is available
        if self.right is not None and (mi > self.right.lower or mi == ~0):
            print("Only right available")
            return self.right.solve(mi, xi)
        elif self.left is not None:
            print("Only left available")
            return self.left.solve(~0, xi)
        else:
            print("None available")
            return -1
        
        
def build_trie(nums):
    nums.sort()
        
    # msb of max(nums)
    max_bit = int(math.log(nums[-1], 2))  # I'll just assume that nums is never empty
    print(max_bit)
        
    def node(start, end, bit, template):
        print(start, end, bit, template, nums[start:end])
        
        if end - start == 1:
            # reached a leaf
            return Trie(0, nums[start], nums[start])
        elif start == end:
            # a partition without values => no Trie-node
            return None
            
        # find pivot for partitioning based on bit-value of specified position (bit)
        part = bisect.bisect_left(nums, template | (1 << bit), start, end)
        print(part)
            
        # build nodes for paritioning       
        res = Trie(bit, None, nums[start])
        res.left = node(start, part, bit - 1, template)
        res.right = node(part, end, bit - 1, template | (1 << bit))
        return res
        
    return node(0, len(nums), max_bit, 0)

class Solution:
    def maximizeXor(self, nums: List[int], queries: List[List[int]]) -> List[int]:
        trie = build_trie(nums)
        return [trie.solve(mi if mi <= nums[-1] else ~0, xi) for xi, mi in queries]
```

I've been a bit lazy and simply used `~0` to signify that the maximum can be ignored since all values in the subtree are smaller than `mi`. The basic idea is that `~0 & x == x` is true for any integer `x`. Not quite as simple as [@DanielHao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66083223/4668606), but capable of handling streams of queries.